# call to function in firefox extension main.js from webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

i want to call a  function in a Firefox extension from webpage.let me explain.i have this function in my main.js script.

```
function extension_function(profname,uurl){

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []); //this gives path to executable
var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(exe);
var args = ['-P',profname, '-no-remote', uurl];
process.run(false, args, args.length);

}
```

now i want to call this function from webpage .if i call  extension_function("p1","www.fb.com") it give me a error extension_function is undefined ...how can i call my add-on function from webpage.

Answer (score 0):

This page might be of interest to you: [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages)

In short, you need to dispatch a custom DOM event in your page and listen for it in your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the Add-on SDK, take a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

You basically have to attach a content script to the webpage (you can do it via PageMod or tab.attach), and then you can communicate via `postMessage` and `port` object.